# A personal computer CPU which does not require any fan to cool it

Tags: processor

I desire to custom-build a totally noiseless personal computer (no fans at all).

The PSU is fanless, 500W. The GPU is fanless. The hard drive is SSD/NVMe.

Is there a modern PC CPU which does not require any fan for cooling?

Comment: Are you sure there aren't? For example I found some "Nettops" which are fanless: https://www.amazon.com/Mini-Computers/b/ref=dp_bc_aui_C_5?ie=UTF8&node=13896591011

Comment: Noctua made a passive cooler and if you put that on an APU it could theoretically be fanless...

Answer (score 0):

The [Noctua-NH-P1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08WC64NN8) is designed to cool a standard CPU passively.